# TCP client server in C#, it doesn't show anything, neither it is connecting

Tags: c#-4.0, c#-3.0

I am trying to connect to TCP client but seems to be not working, following is my code snippet, when I am running this application ,It doesn't show IP it is running and the port it is listening to.

```
public class serv {
public static void Main() {
try {
    IPAddress ipAd = IPAddress.Parse("172.21.5.99");
     // use local m/c IP address, and 
     // use the same in the client


    TcpListener myList=new TcpListener(ipAd,8001);



    Console.WriteLine("The server is running at port 8001...");    
    Console.WriteLine("The local End point is  :" + 
                      myList.LocalEndpoint );
    Console.WriteLine("Waiting for a connection.....");

    Socket s=myList.AcceptSocket();
    Console.WriteLine("Connection accepted from " + s.RemoteEndPoint);

    byte[] b=new byte[100];
    int k=s.Receive(b);
    Console.WriteLine("Recieved...");
    for (int i=0;i<k;i++)
        Console.Write(Convert.ToChar(b[i]));

    ASCIIEncoding asen=new ASCIIEncoding();
    s.Send(asen.GetBytes("The string was recieved by the server."));
    Console.WriteLine("\nSent Acknowledgement");
    s.Close();
    myList.Stop();

}
catch (Exception e) {
    Console.WriteLine("Error..... " + e.StackTrace);
}    
}
```

}

---

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;
using System.Net.Sockets;


public class clnt {

  public static void Main() {

    try {
        TcpClient tcpclnt = new TcpClient();
        Console.WriteLine("Connecting.....");

        tcpclnt.Connect("172.21.5.99",8001);
        // use the ipaddress as in the server program

        Console.WriteLine("Connected");
        Console.Write("Enter the string to be transmitted : ");

        String str=Console.ReadLine();
        Stream stm = tcpclnt.GetStream();

        ASCIIEncoding asen= new ASCIIEncoding();
        byte[] ba=asen.GetBytes(str);
        Console.WriteLine("Transmitting.....");

        stm.Write(ba,0,ba.Length);

        byte[] bb=new byte[100];
        int k=stm.Read(bb,0,100);

        for (int i=0;i<k;i++)
            Console.Write(Convert.ToChar(bb[i]));

        tcpclnt.Close();
    }

    catch (Exception e) {
        Console.WriteLine("Error..... " + e.StackTrace);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Brother,

you didn't specified the start

after this line

TcpListener myList=new TcpListener(ipAd,8001);

put

myList.Start();

this is for listening the port

Hope this works !